# Does the OP get reputation back if a down-voted answer they posted is deleted for moderation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers

If a user posts an answer that is, say, rude/offensive, and the answer is both down-voted by other users and ultimately deleted *by a moderator* (not by the OP) due to flags, does the user who posted the answer get the reputation back? Is the effect on reputation the same for all flags / deletion reasons?

I found: [Regain of reputation from downvoted and deleted answers - update FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197507/regain-of-reputation-from-downvoted-and-deleted-answers-update-faq?rq=1), which deals with the *voters* getting reputation back.

I also found: [Redeem reputation for deleted negative answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/reedem-reputation-for-deleted-negative-answers?rq=1), which deals with deleting your *own* answer.

I haven't been able to find anything regarding reputation effects for the posters of an answer that was deleted by somebody else.

Comment: I'm not sure about all cases but a deletion from spam/offensive flags carries a 100 rep penalty

Comment: @michaelb958 Thanks. Just to clarify: From that FAQ and RichardTingle's point, does that mean that if a question with downvotes is deleted by a moderator because of, e.g., a not-an-answer flag, the asker *will* get the reputation back if the post is under 60 days old? And the 60 day limit does not apply to posts deleted from spam/offensive flags?

Comment: If it is downvoted they will get the rep back at any age. Only >+3 post reputation is kept when older than 60 days

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, the user does get their reputation back from downvoted posts when they are deleted, even by a moderator. Reputation changes are cached, so it may take a little while. Here's a small portion of a reputation report from a post I deleted earlier.

[image: Restored reputation]

Comment: -6 from a downvote? Is there something the staff aren't telling us about moderator voting powers?

Comment: But they are hit with a permanent -100 for spam/offensive regardless of age (and votes), correct?

Comment: @JasonC Yes, that's correct. I think they still get reputation back for any downvotes they'd had, but the -100 usually more than compensates for that.

Comment: And if the question has a combination of offensive flags and not-an-answer flags, are moderators given a choice to close because of the offensive flags, so that the user still sees permanent negative repercussions for offensive posts (if moderator decides "offensive" actually applies)?

Comment: @michaelb958 - It may have had 3 downvotes, which means if the post is removed, the -6 becomes a +6.

Comment: @JasonC Yes, we can cast our own spam/offensive flag to apply the -100 immediately.  Or, if we disagree with spam/offensive flags, we can remove them before accepting other flags as helpful.

Comment: @jmort253 Ah, so just a giant-S bug.

Comment: @michaelb958 Yeah, I guess that's a snippet from the asker's reputation log; it says "downvote" rather than "downvoted".

Comment: @BilltheLizard Thanks. Are spam/offensive penalties in a users' reputation log invisible to other normal users?

Comment: @JasonC Yes, the spam/offensive penalties are hidden from everyone except moderators and the affected user.