# Having a post deleted for moderation reasons shouldn't give you the reputation back

Tags: discussion, feature-request, rude-or-abusive

Related (but not identical): [Does the OP get reputation back if a down-voted answer they posted is deleted for moderation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251125/does-the-op-get-reputation-back-if-a-down-voted-answer-they-posted-is-deleted-fo)

Note: that question is asking whether the OP *does*, in fact, get the reputation back, but I'm claiming that they *shouldn't* get the reputation back.

Recently, someone posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223870/what-is-the-fastest-pc-per-dollar-cost-for-net-development) (10K+ because I didn't capture a screenshot before it was deleted and I don't have 10K yet) with the disclaimer that they were aware that it was off-topic and it would probably draw downvotes and close votes but that they were posting it anyway.

> What is the fastest PC for .Net Development?
>   This will probably get closed, downvoted, etc...
>   But I would like to know what people think the best PC's are for .Net Development.
>   I'm currently using a Dell Inspiron 5559. It's pretty good - a bit sluggish when I have a lot of applications running.

Naturally, it *was*, in fact, heavily downvoted, closed, and deleted (I'm not sure whether it was deleted by a moderator or by 20k+ users). However, the OP got the rep he had lost through downvotes back right after it was deleted.

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348708/4032703) seems to imply that we should *not* flag things like that as rude or abusive (although I kind of wish we could), so really, what are the penalties for this kind of behavior (other than a possible eventual question ban if they do stuff like that often enough)?

In cases like this, it seems like the OP should *not* get the rep back that they lost through downvotes (or that there should be some other kind of penalty). (Especially so given that the OP was knowingly flaunting the rules in this case; it wasn't just a case of him not bothering to read the help center).

Comment: -9 isn't *that* heavily downvoted.  Also, consider the more common case; what if the user was at 1 rep already, got an upvote, then had that rep obliterated by other downvotes?  What would the benefit be?  (They'd also lose the upvote, too.)  What are you trying to accomplish with this feature?

Comment: @Makoto Would've been -10 if I hadn't ran out of downvotes this morning :)

Comment: What I'm saying is, that's really not a lot of downvotes.  (It also did get 10 downvotes, by the way.)  I'd still like clarity into the intent of this.  What would this really accomplish that the other quality monitors don't seem to cover?

Comment: @EJoshuaS So how would the world be any different if this user had 15 less rep than they have now?  Keep in mind that if you don't reverse reputation actions for deleted post there will be *way* more reputation *added* to the site than removed (given that upvotes add so much more rep than downvotes remove).

Comment: @Servy Fair point - it seems like there should be *some* kind of penalty, though, even if it's something other than that. Right now, there probably won't be any lasting effects beyond contributing to a possible eventual question ban or suspension.

Comment: @EJoshuaS That would be true even if your proposal went through.

Comment: The fact that their question was downvoted *at all* is punishment enough.  That inches them closer to a q-ban, since that question would count as "poorly received", even if it's deleted now.

Comment: @Makoto That's true, but they're *not* question-banned now.

Comment: @Makoto The main intent is that there should be some kind of penalty for cases where the OP didn't voluntarily remove bad content, especially if they knew it was off topic from the outset (like the OP here apparently did). I'm also inclined to think that we *should* be able to flag questions like that as being rude/abusive (although the answer I linked to implies that we shouldn't).

Comment: @EJoshuaS 'if I hadn't ran out of downvotes this morning' for some questions, it would be nice if we could go overdrawn for a couple days:)

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, I was really irritated that I ran out, tag cleanups are killer for running out of downvotes and close votes.

Comment: You are proposing to make DVs punitive.  That is a horrible idea and would destroy the usefulness of DVs if ever implemented.  Absolutely key to usage is that they are cast on posts, never people.  And specific to questions, only serve as a signal to SO contributors which ones should be answered and which ignored.  Make it punitive and it will be abused badly and give everybody an actual good reason to hate SO moderation.

Comment: It is particularly galling when a user actually says in their question that they understand their question is off-topic and are asking anyway. (I don't understand *why* they think doing it is a good idea either.) But to be fair, lots of users are doing that anyway and just aren't saying so. Other users didn't know the rules but make it clear they don't care after they are explained. Attempting to further punish users who say they are deliberately breaking the rules won't actually stop those users from doing so. They'll just stop saying it out loud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine that, because of all the downvotes, he decided to delete it *himself* before moderation deletion. What would be the difference? And in that case he'd get his rep points back, we all agree that it should remain so.

Ok, he got his rep points back (because he *had* rep, most of those off-topic posts come from 1-rep new users, so that's kind of a corner case), but the downvotes still count for a possible post ban.

The number of downvotes for a post ban is kept secret to avoid people toying with the limit but it exists.

So even if he got his rep points back, continuously posting stuff like that (and deleting it or having it deleted, or keeping it non-deleted) will have him banned.

Note that you can lose 100 rep if an answer is flagged 6 times as rude or abusive ([What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor)).

(in the case of this question, ok it's blatantly off-topic, but maybe on-topic for another SE site, and definitely not rude so it doesn't qualify in my opinion)

Comment: It's 6 flags on the same post (or a single moderator flag, ours are binding), not flags on 6 answers.

Comment: ok so you _really_ have to be super-rude... but I believe that moderators can also decide to ban a user on human decision as well (thanks for the edit BTW)

Comment: No, we can't apply a post ban, nor can we lift it. Post bans are entirely automated.

Comment: Yes, we can suspend users, but deleting a downvoted question is not usually a reason to; there would have been more history before that.

Comment: good to know (not that I'm planning to get banned or such :)) you can warn the user at least.